# How do I unlock/get Jason and Leatherface?

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

I completed story mode of the game and explored some of the krypt unlocking stuff but I don't have Leatherface and Jason how do I unlock them or have them?

Answer (score 3):

Both Jason and Leatherface are DLC characters that are purchased from the store. You can either buy them individually or as part of packs.

Jason is part of Kombat pack 1 and Leatherface is part of Kombat pack 2. Obviously, additional characters come with these packs.

If you have the XL edition of the game the packs should automatically be in your account.

Once the DLCs are installed, the characters should become available to play with and against.